# How to add Images to CListCtrl in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, imagelist

How do you add Images to a `ClistCtrl` in MFC? I have tried and found that it's quite difficult.

I used `CImageList` to add images and then passed it to the `CListCtrl`. Can you provide some samples?

```
m_sentToCListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("Item Name"), LVCFMT_LEFT,nColInterval*3);     
m_sentToCListCtrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("Value"),LVCFMT_LEFT, nColInterval);
m_sentToCListCtrl.InsertColumn(2, _T("Time"), LVCFMT_LEFT, rect.Width()-4*nColInterval);
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_sentToCListCtrl.m_hWnd,LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES );

// Create 256 color image lists     
HIMAGELIST hSentToList =ImageList_Create(84,71, ILC_COLOR8 |ILC_MASK , 8, 1);
m_sentToImageList.Attach(hSentToList);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add some bitmaps to your `CImageList` after you have created it. Something like this:

```
m_myImageList.Create(84,71, ILC_COLOR8 |ILC_MASK , 8, 1);

CBitmap bm;
bm.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
m_myImageList.Add(&bm, RGB(0, 0, 0));
bm.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP2);
m_myImageList.Add(&bm, RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

Then, attach it to the `CListCtrl`:

```
m_sentToCListCtrl.SetImageList(&m_imageList, LVSIL_SMALL);
```

Finally, you add items to your `CListCtrl` by using the `InsertItem` method:

```
LVITEM lvItem;
lvItem.iItem = 0;
lvItem.iImage = 0;    // image index that refers to your image list
lvItem.pszText = L"Item 1";
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

m_sentToCListCtrl.InsertItem(&lvItem);
```

For more info refer to [`CListCtrl` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There are examples too.

Comment: Addon: If you have a bmp preloaded in your resources, you can skip imagelist.add and do: m_myImageList.Create( IDB_TOOLBAR256, 15, 10, RGB( 0, 0, 0 ) ); m_sentToCListCtrl.SetImageList( &myImageList, LVSIL_NORMAL );. This is all documented in on-Line resources.