# Display bmp image and text in List Control in MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, dev-c++

I want to display bmp image and text in list control in MFC ,
It should display different bmp image for different item , **but it display same bmp for all the items**

Here is my code

```
CListCtrl m_cParentListContrl;
CImageList m_ImageList[3];

m_ImageList[0].Create(IDB_BMP_LISTCTRL,128,1,RGB(150,150,100));
m_ImageList[1].Create(IDB_BMP_CHECKBOX,128,1,RGB(150,150,100));
m_ImageList[2].Create(IDB_BMP_COMBOBOX,128,1,RGB(150,150,100));

m_cParentListContrl.SetImageList(m_ImageList,LVSIL_NORMAL);

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    val.Format(_T("List ::%d"),i);
    //third parameter for index of image to be displayed
    // if that replaced by i to 0 then it display single image else not
    m_cParentListContrl.InsertItem(i,val,i);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using three separate image lists for three separate bitmaps?  I think you're misunderstanding how an image list works for a CListCtrl.  I think you want one image list that contains three images.

Comment: I,m new to MFC so can you give a small example

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531065/how-to-add-images-to-clistctrl-in-mfc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531065/how-to-add-images-to-clistctrl-in-mfc)

Comment: You might think you had created an ImageList with 3 images, but no! You really created an array of three ImageLists! I never thought it could be interpreted the way you did!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to reduce your current 3 bitmaps to one continuous strip bitmap with your 3 images one after each other:

```
CImageList m_ImageList;

m_ImageList.Create(128,128, ILC_COLOR24, 3, 1);
m_ImageList.SetImageCount(3);

CBitmap bmpListCtrl;
bmpListCtrl.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_LISTCTRL);
m_ImageList.Replace(0, bmpListCtrl, (CBitmap*)NULL);

CBitmap bmpCheckBox;
bmpCheckBox.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_CHECKBOX);
m_ImageList.Replace(1, bmpCheckBox, (CBitmap*)NULL);

CBitmap bmpComboBox;
bmpComboBox.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_COMBOBOX);
m_ImageList.Replace(2, bmpComboBox, (CBitmap*)NULL);
```